# Send HTML email via C# with SmtpClient

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email, smtpclient

How do I send an HTML email? I use the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c/707892#707892) to send emails with `SmtpClient`, but they're always plain text, so the link in the example message below is not formatted as such.

```html
<p>Welcome to SiteName. To activate your account, visit this URL: 
    <a href="http://SiteName.com/a?key=1234">http://SiteName.com/a?key=1234</a>.
</p>
```

How do I enable HTML in the e-mail messages I send?

Comment: ropstah: TBH i was confused and wrote in one of your comments that there is no IsBodyHtml in SmtpClient. Josiah is who showed me to do it with MailMessage.

Answer (score 106):

**This is what I do:**

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
client.Send(mail);
```

Note that I set the mail message html to true: `mail.IsBodyHtml = true;`

Comment: Worth noting that both `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` implement `IDisposable`, and need to be disposed accordingly.

Comment: I use C# windows form to send email in this way. How to embed an image to the email? `string body = "Hi there... <h1> Test Title </h1> </br> <h3> test body </h3> <img src='image.jpg' alt='Image'>";' I just added my image to the bin/debug folder. but it is not working.

Answer (score 22):

I believe it was something like:

```
mailObject.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Answer (score 20):

`IsBodyHtml = true` is undoubtedly the most important part.

But if you want to provide an email with both a text/plain part and a text/html part composed as alternates, it is also possible using the `AlternateView` class:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
AlternateView plainView = AlternateView
     .CreateAlternateViewFromString("Some plaintext", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
// We have something to show in real old mail clients.
msg.AlternateViews.Add(plainView); 
string htmlText = "The <b>fancy</b> part.";
AlternateView htmlView = 
     AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlText, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html");
msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView); // And a html attachment to make sure.
msg.Body = htmlText;  // But the basis is the html body
msg.IsBodyHtml = true; // But the basis is the html body
```

Comment: Is the `AlternateView` for `htmlView` really necessary? Because you already set the body to be `htmlText`. Isn't it redundant to set it again as alternate view?

Comment: Not only it's necessary, but also important that it's added after the plain alternate view. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188605/gmail-displays-plain-text-email-instead-html.
But specifying Body and IsBodyHtml is not necessary if you have added html alternate view.

Answer (score 8):

Apply the correct encoding of the Mailbody.

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea , you can add a check box to your project for sending email as html as an option for user , and add this code to enable it :

```
         MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);

         if(checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked )
           {
               mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
           }

         SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");

         client.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using **Mailkit**,We can use TextBody,HtmlBody and Both for message body. Just write this code. It will help you

```
            MimeMessage mailMessage = new MimeMessage();
            mailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(senderName, sender@address.com));
            mailMessage.Sender = new MailboxAddress(senderName, sender@address.com);
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(emailid, emailid));
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.ReplyTo.Add(new MailboxAddress(replyToAddress));
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            var builder = new BodyBuilder();
            builder.HtmlBody = "Hello There";
            mailMessage.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();            
            try
            {
                using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtpClient.Connect("HostName", "Port", MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.None);
                    smtpClient.Authenticate("user@name.com", "password");

                    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine("Success");
                }
            }
            catch (SmtpCommandException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());                
            }
```

Comment: The builder is not used in this context

Comment: For BodyBuilder you must have MimeKit.

Comment: No, i meant after `builder.HtmlBody = "Hello There";` builder variable is not used at all.