# Gmail API still replaces text/plain alternative body part with automatically generated one from HTML

Tags: gmail-api, mime

I'm using GMail API to send a MIME email. The text part of the email always gets regenerated from the HTML part.

I have tried various variations in MIME and how I structure the headers. Another man reported the same problem a few years back:

[Gmail API replaces text/plain alternative body part with automatically generated one from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431526/gmail-api-replaces-text-plain-alternative-body-part-with-automatically-generated)

The message shows correctly in GMail interface "Sent" items, if I view the original of the message. However, the message arrives at the destination with text part replaced with HTML part.  I tested it with several destinations, including Yahoo Mail.

The relevant part of the input multipart message is:

```
--0000000000d81f74059447a2ad02
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Hello plain text

--0000000000d81f74059447a2ad02
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<b>Hello html</b>

--0000000000d81f74059447a2ad02--
```

Viewing the raw message at the target (Yahoo Mail) shows this:

```
--00000000000046bd1105948482e9
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="00000000000046bd0e05948482e7"

--00000000000046bd0e05948482e7
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

*Hello html*

--00000000000046bd0e05948482e7
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<b>Hello html</b>

--00000000000046bd0e05948482e7--
```

Here's the full test case,

https://gist.github.com/borisreitman/448e2699c267221ebbf430b64346baaa

Notice that the text part now contains "Hello html" instead of the original "Hello plain text".

Comment: I found an open bug in GMail API reported back in 2016.https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760128

Answer (score -1):

### The proper syntax for the message composition is confusing

You need to past your plain text content **BOTH** in the `text/plain` and `text/html` part of the message.

Modify your code message body as following and it will work as a charm:

```
--0000000000d81f74059447a2ad02
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Hello plain text

*Hello html*

--0000000000d81f74059447a2ad02
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr">Hello plain text<br><div><br></div><div><b>Hello html</b><br></div></div>

--0000000000d81f74059447a2ad02--
```

Comment: Sorry, I want the two parts to be different.  For example, let's say the HTML part has an advertisement -- I don't want it to be present in the text part. The text part should have absolute minimum content. The HTML email can be fancy.

Comment: Then you can leave *Hello html* out from the text/plain part, but you do need to include `
Hello plain text` in the text/html part, otherwise it won't be included as you have noticed.