# Gmail loses the html formatting of emails sent with Odoo

Tags: email, gmail, odoo

My company migrated their CRM starting to use Odoo, and then I proceeded to configure the external mail server (gmail), the @catchall parameter, and then define the odoo mail templates.

So far I have no problems, and everything works as I expect, so the mails are correctly and received.
However, I have a problem with viewing the emails ... let me explain.
Sent an email through Odoo, I see it correctly in html format, so by accessing the gmail email account via browser and opening the message, also in this case it is correctly formatted and displayed as html.

However, the recipient of the e-mail upon receipt loses the html formatting and therefore receives the e-mail displaying it in plain-text.

On the gmail settings I have already configured to send messages in html, I tried to disable it and then re-enable it but nothing happens.

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. We have tried several configurations both in the Google account and in the server. It only happens with GMail mail. Using any other service does not happen.

There's an answer here that I still can't implement, but it could be of help.

[GMail displays plain text email instead HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188605/gmail-displays-plain-text-email-instead-html)

Comment: The problem is related to the security settings in GMail. You must enter to the Security settings and activate the access to less secure apps. It is also important to have 2-factor authentication disabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A known reason for the issue was the appending of a footer in Google. Odoo has recently released a fix for all versions from 14.0 onwards: https://github.com/odoo/odoo/pull/108499. However, if they encounter other cases, Odoo Enterprise customers can open a support ticket and users of the Community edition can submit a Github issue.