# Writing HTML code in C#

Tags: c#, html, html-table, html-email

What I want to do is;

```
for (int i = 0; i < thexfiles.Length; i++)
{
    tosend = tosend + "<tr><td>"+thexfiles[i]+"</td><td>"+thexdates[i]+"</td></tr><tr>";
}
mail.Body = tosend;
```

I want to insert the data into a table in a C# code (using html perhaps?), so when it's mailed it looks clean.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? You're already showing us your own answer...

Comment: well that code doesnt work, it just sends <tr><td>+thexfiles[i]+</td><td>+thexdates[i]+</td></tr><tr> to mail

Comment: Add the table tags and set mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

Comment: Please use google search or stackoverflow search before asking - there are plenty info there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329922/send-html-email-via-c-sharp-asp-net

Comment: What type is `thexfiles`? Have you tried `thexfiles[i].ToString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < thexfiles.Length; i++)
{
    tosend = tosend + "<tr><td>"+thexfiles[i]+"</td><td>"+thexdates[i]+"</td></tr>";
}

tosend = "<html><table>" + tosend + "</table></html>";

mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
mail.Body = tosend;
```

And that's it, the mail body will be shown in HTML table.

Comment: + is just for string concatenation..and how can you say that it's slower..it is faster than `StringBuilder.Append`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<table>");
    sb.Append("<tr><td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td></tr>");

    for (int i = 0; i < thexfiles.Length; i++)
        sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td></tr>", thexfiles[i], thexdates[i]);

    sb.Append("</table>");

    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Body = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: you forgot the `<tbody>` tag :)

Comment: <tbody> is an optional tag, and now a days we would use <div> to create the layout

Comment: how would i add another line just outside the loop, to show the column names ??

Comment: You should use `<th>` rather than `<td>` for the column names.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the class: `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` make sure after assigning the content to the `Body` property you also set the property `IsBodyHtml` to `true` .

that should work.