# Send automatic emails when payments are recorded to database from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, asp.net-web-api, email

Ok, here's what's going on:  I am developing a property management web app in ASP.NET for my father's small business.  He would like the web app to automatically send a receipt/balance/notification via email when he enters a payment from a tenant.  He would also like it to send monthly emails on a certain date with each tenant's balance.

Is there a third party API or something similar that would have those capabilities?  I have already implemented Twilio to send automatic text messages, I just need to get the emails to send automatically now.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You did find [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)?

Comment: you can use a CLR store proc and invoke it on insert/update trigger..similar to  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1795/send-email-from-sql-server-express-using-a-clr-stored-procedure/

Comment: For sending mail you can use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494311/sending-mail-using-c-sharp-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

use **[Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)**

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245975/quartz-net-setup-in-an-asp-net-website) will also be helpful.

with Quart.net you can send mail monthly. I've done a little study and with quart.net now i am able to send mail after every 7 days.