# How to send email

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am New in `Asp.net`, i need to send email from `Asp.net` using my `Outlook`.
I have one button in asp  and when i click button(send) i want to send email.
I tried to use Hotmail and `Gmail` but remote server in blocked.
If you don't understand my question please tell me.
I tried this:

```
         var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "outlook.mycompany.local",
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myEmail@mycommpany.com", "myPassword")
        };

        var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
        {
            Subject = "Test Subject",
            Body = "FOLLOW THE WHITE RABBIT",
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            From = new MailAddress("myemail@mycommapny.com")
        };
        // you can add multiple email addresses here
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("friendEmail@Company.com"));

        // and here you're actually sending the message
        smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Exeption Show: `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated`
Please how can i do that ?

Comment: By Outlook, do you actually mean Exchange ? Outlook can't send emails if it's not connected to an email server, it's just a client.

Comment: You have to use real values for EmailFrom, EmailTo etc. Also make sure that EmailFrom is an address recognized and allowed by SMTP server, otherwise it will be blocked as a spam attempt

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Yes it connected in email server. we are company and we use outlook to communicate.And i need to send email to everyone from asp. this is my task to do :S

Comment: @PeterrPann Sorry about that, my mind was blanking

Answer (score 1):

Sending outbound email from an ASP.net web site can be problematic.  Even if you get the SMTP information right, you still have to deal with:

- Sender Policy Framework (SPF)
- Whitelists/Blacklists
- Validation
- Bouncebacks

It's very difficult to do this yourself, which is why you might want to consider using a service provider instead.  You simply use their API (often a REST call), and they do the rest.  Here are three such providers:

- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/)
- [Mandrill](http://www.mandrill.com/)
- [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/)

Mandrill has a low-end free plan, and so does SendGrid if you are using it with Windows Azure.  And they are all reasonably affordable, even for the larger plans.

I highly recommend using one of these with their own API instead of using `System.Net.Mail` yourself.  But if you want, they also can act as an SMTP relay for you so you can use their SMTP servers and keep your `System.Net.Mail` code intact.

Comment: Okej Matt thanks for you Answer

Answer (score 1):

First of all get the company SMTP server settings (from your sys admins I guess), then you can do something like this:

```
// setting up the server
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "your.company.smtp.server",
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    EnableSsl = true, // <-- see if you need this
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("account_to_use", "password")
};

var message = new MailMessage
{
    Subject = "Test Subject",
    Body = "FOLLOW THE WHITE RABBIT",
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    From = new MailAddress("from@company.com")
};
// you can add multiple email addresses here
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("neo@matrix.com"));

// and here you're actually sending the message
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

Comment: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated .. Exeption ?? @Dimitar

Comment: Check username and password. And make sure you can get to the server. I am not able to get to my SMTP server from inside my work network.

Comment: @PeterrPann see if you need to enable SSL ? (again not sure about your server setup), also try a domain account with network credential -> `domain\\account`, `password`. In case you need SSL check my `SmtpClient` edit.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function. and one thing you have to store you email smtp login and password in web config file

```
/// <summary>
/// Send Email 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="strFrom"></param>
/// <param name="strTo"></param>
/// <param name="strSubject"></param>
/// <param name="strBody"></param>
/// <param name="strAttachmentPath"></param>
/// <param name="IsBodyHTML"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public Boolean sendemail(String strFrom, string strTo, string strSubject, string strBody, string strAttachmentPath, bool IsBodyHTML)
{
    Array arrToArray;
    char[] splitter = { ';' };
    arrToArray = strTo.Split(splitter);
    MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
    mm.From = new MailAddress(strFrom);
    mm.Subject = strSubject;
    mm.Body = strBody;
    mm.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHTML;
    //mm.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("replyto@xyz.com");
    foreach (string s in arrToArray)
    {
        mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(s));
    }
    if (strAttachmentPath != "")
    {
        try
        {
            //Add Attachment
            Attachment attachFile = new Attachment(strAttachmentPath);
            mm.Attachments.Add(attachFile);
        }
        catch { }
    }
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    try
    {
        smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailServer"].ToString();
        smtp.EnableSsl = true; //Depending on server SSL Settings true/false
        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        NetworkCred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailUserName"].ToString();
        NetworkCred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailPassword"].ToString();
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;//Specify your port No;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        mm.Dispose();
        smtp = null;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: i need to use WEB.Mail or NET.Mail ??

Comment: they are same. you can use it in your asp.net Application

Answer (score 0):

Try Amazon Simple Email Service (http://aws.amazon.com/ses/).  If you're new to Amazon Web Services (AWS) there might be a learning curve.  However, once you're familiar with their SDK which can be found on Nuget (AWSSDK) the process is very straight-forward (Amazon does have a lot of little wrapper classes which can be quirky).

So, to answer the question "How to send email?", it looks something like:

```
        var fromAddress = "from@youraddress.com";

        var toAddresses = new Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model.Destination("someone@somedestination.com");

        var subject = new Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model.Content("Message");

        var body= new Body(new Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model.Content("Body"));

        var message = new Message(subject , body);

        var client = ConfigUtility.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient;

        var request= new Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model.SendEmailRequest();

        request.WithSource(fromAddress)
                            .WithDestination(toAddresses)
                            .WithMessage(message );
        try
        {
            client.SendEmail(request);
        }
        catch (Amazon.SimpleEmail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceException sesError)
        {
            throw new SupplyitException("There was a problem sending your email", sesError);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to below links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/371417/Send-Mail-Contact-Form-using-ASP-NET-and-Csharp

[send email asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704042/send-email-asp-net-c-sharp)

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: I tried that but not work to me :S

Comment: Link-only answers are considered poor on StackOverflow - links often have a limited lifespan.  You should update your answer to include some detail of how to solve the problem.

Comment: try setting EnableSSL property to false.