# How to send data to outlook body?

Tags: asp.net, email, outlook

we have an app with a form. When the user clicks on "send" I want outlook(!) to open and there appeared html table in the body, which the user can still edit. Help, how to implement it?
At first I wanted to use mailto, but found that it only supports text, not html.
Don't criticize me too much, I'm new to this case, thanks

Comment: You can achieve the functionality you want by sending the email directly from the server side of your Website, here are some examples: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329922/send-html-email-via-c-sharp-with-smtpclient 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628683/how-to-send-html-formatted-email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running that code on the server (ASP)? You cannot launch Outlook on the client machine, that must be done by the client side script only. And that will only work if you are running IE and your site is marked safe.

Try to simply serve an EML file - the client side browser will open it using the local mail client. To make sure the message is sendable, set the `X-Unsent` MIME header to 1.

Comment: Yes, on Web Forms. I need to take data from form and set emails into mailto some way..

Comment: mailto won't work as you have already found out - it does not support HTML and attachments. What's wrong with serving an EML file?