# How to append User Id and Password to a HTML email template. file Dynamically

Tags: c#, html, string, html-email

I am creating an application which will send an User Id and Auto Generated Password to the user via email. I have the User Id and Password generated with me and the Email template as well.
I want to append these data in to a HTML template file.

```
string emailData = "Hi " + UserName + " Please use this " + Password + "as your password to login in to the Application.";
```

I want to add this string to a span tag of the HTML template.

Comment: Sounds like your question is really how do I programmatically send a HTML email, is that right? In which case, there are plenty of answers already here

Comment: This is my exact question.How do I append a html string inside a HTML template programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send HTML email via C# with SmtpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329922/send-html-email-via-c-sharp-with-smtpclient)