# DataTable to Html Table sending as mail on Gmail

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to display a data table in a mail send via gmail, but gmail does not display the html file, the message is displayed as text.

**Here is my code to tansform the data Table to html file**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Procedures procedures = new Procedures();
        DataTable info = new DataTable();
        if (procedures.GT99_Total_Ventas_PORSECTOR(info) == true)
        {
            SendMail sendMail = new SendMail();
            sendMail.Send("Report22", toHTML_Table(info));
        }
    }

    public static string toHTML_Table(DataTable dt)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0) return ""; // enter code here

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append("<html>");
        builder.Append("<head>");
        builder.Append("<title>");
        builder.Append("Page-");
        builder.Append(Guid.NewGuid());
        builder.Append("</title>");
        builder.Append("</head>");
        builder.Append("<body>");
        builder.Append("<table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' ");
        builder.Append("style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;'>");
        builder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");
        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {
            builder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'><b>");
            builder.Append(c.ColumnName);
            builder.Append("</b></td>");
        }
        builder.Append("</tr>");
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            builder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");
            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                builder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
                builder.Append(r[c.ColumnName]);
                builder.Append("</td>");
            }
            builder.Append("</tr>");
        }
        builder.Append("</table>");
        builder.Append("</body>");
        builder.Append("</html>");

        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

**But when i recive the file in gmail i just see the plain text no the table**

```
<html><head><title>Page-6e3549a9-b725-4325-bf72-c70f06f09a9e</title></head><body><table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;'><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'><b>Total</b></td><td align='left' valign='top'><b>Sector</b></td><td align='left' valign='top'><b>SectorVenta</b></td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>757062950591,570</td><td align='left' valign='top'>11</td><td align='left' valign='top'>11-Calzados</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>61837742616,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>12</td><td align='left' valign='top'>12-Marroquinería</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>9797449070,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>13</td><td align='left' valign='top'>13-Bazar</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>117219098406,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>14</td><td align='left' valign='top'>14-Prendas de Vestir</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>1140370260,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>15</td><td align='left' valign='top'>15-Juguetes</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>20760307536,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>16</td><td align='left' valign='top'>16-Accesorios</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>62053668890,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>17</td><td align='left' valign='top'>17-Cosméticos</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>26462500,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>18</td><td align='left' valign='top'>18-Ferretería</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>21847354730,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>21</td><td align='left' valign='top'>21-Hogar</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>5082512450,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>22</td><td align='left' valign='top'>22-Deportes</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>1157622000,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>23</td><td align='left' valign='top'>23-Bebés</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>182475126340,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>27</td><td align='left' valign='top'>27-Alimentos</td></tr><tr align='left' valign='top'><td align='left' valign='top'>33726265182,000</td><td align='left' valign='top'>99</td><td align='left' valign='top'>99-Otros</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

**This is how i send the email**

```
public class SendMail
{
    private Email emailConfiguration;

    public SendMail()
    {
        emailConfiguration = new Email();
    }

    public bool Send(string subject, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient()
            {
                Host = emailConfiguration.SMTP,
                Port = Int32.Parse(emailConfiguration.PortMail),
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential()
                {
                    UserName = emailConfiguration.FromMail,
                    Password = emailConfiguration.FromPasswordMail
                }

            };

            MailAddress FromEmail = new MailAddress(emailConfiguration.FromMail, emailConfiguration.FromName);
            MailAddress ToEmail = new MailAddress(emailConfiguration.ToMail, emailConfiguration.ToName);
            MailMessage Message = new MailMessage()
            {
                From = FromEmail,
                Subject = subject,
                Body = message,
            };
            Message.To.Add(ToEmail);

            client.Send(Message);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT: Added who i send the mail.

Comment: How do you send the email? Unless you explicitly specify that the content is HTML, it will be treated as plain text. This isn't a problem with .NET, that's how email works

Comment: I added the class that sends the email

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27413060/215752

Comment: Thank you Hogan that is the solution to my question

Comment: see answer by faester -- you have to make both text and html versions

Comment: You're sending plain text. In any case, *DON'T USE SmptClient*. The class is obsolete and its own documentation page strongly warns against it, suggesting to use MailKit instead