# Error Sending an Email in a .NET Program

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

Ok so I am doing a code in C# to send to a persons email a message, here is the code:

```
MailAddress EmailFrom = new MailAddress("panchosalazardeurquidi5@gmail.com");
MailAddress EmailTo = new MailAddress(txtTo);
MailMessage Email = new MailMessage(EmailFrom, EmailTo);
Email.Subject = txtTitle;
Email.Body = txtContext;
SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient("www.gmail.com/");
Client.Send(Email);
```

My principal problem is that I get an error that says:

> SocketException: No such host is known System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName (System.String 
>   hostName)
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect
>   (System.String hostname, Int32 port)
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor
>   (System.String hostname, Int32 port)

And says that the problem is on

```
Client.Send(Email);
```

So, could please some one help me with this.

Comment: You might want to cut your code example down to the minimum that still shows the problem...

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with Unity 3d.

Comment: Yeah I know, but is only for extra information because sometimes is important to know what program you are using.

Comment: and sometimes you don't need the context. Please narrow down your question now that you know that the answer has nothing to do with anything except your bad URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"www.gmail.com/"` is not a valid host name (it has a slash at the end). It might (also) not actually be GMail's SMTP host.

Comment: If you are using gmail as your host, check this article...  note the port and the fact that EnableSSL is set to true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c

Comment: thanks for the answer but know I get another error saying: Assets/mail.cs(36,16): error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Net.NetworkCredential' to `System.Net.ICredentialsByHost'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Uriel - a quick hint for you. Stack Overflow isn't a forum for a conversation, it's a Q&A site. If you have a different question that's come up now you've solved this problem, post a new question - many more people will see it that way.