# sending email using gmail account on local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I am using gmail for sending email in my asp.net application. Email works fine if I send email on server but if I try to send emails on local machine it give error. I placed break poin in code and when send method is called it shows error box with heading "Smtp exception was unhandled by user code" and in detail it says "Faliur sending mail".

If I continued on browser it shows error page with these details:

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Below is my code, kindly guide me.

Thanks.

```
  protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string _Message = GetAdminEmailMessage();        

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    NetworkCredential mailAuthentication = new NetworkCredential("myaccount@gmail.com", "mypassword");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("mc5678@hotmail.com"));
    message.From = new MailAddress("myaccount@gmail.com");
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Subject = "Local test email";
    message.Body = _Message;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Credentials = mailAuthentication;
    smtp.Send(message);

}
```

Comment: Ports blocked? or maybe your IP are blocked with gmail? I would check that I could connect with same settings from Outlook or similar before troubleshooting further

Comment: StefanE I tried usign Outlook to connect to gmail and the the follwoign error, I am sorry I am not getting it can u plz adice.   The connection to the server has failed. Account: 'smtp.gmail.com', Server: 'smtp.gmail.com', Protocol: POP3, Port: 110, Secure(SSL): No, Socket Error: 10060, Error Number: 0x800CCC0E

Answer (score 1):

Error code 0x800CCC0E indicates that the port has been blocked: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191687

Try telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 - Can you connect?

If your port is unblocked and your credentials correct, then the code in the accepted answer for this question should work..

[Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
                EnableSsl = true
            };
            client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hearm I tiped telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 on command propt and it shows "220 mx.google.com ESMTP s9sn421715wby.4" I m sorry I am not aware of telnet is it means it is connected ?

Comment: If port is blicked what I can do to unblock the port or any solution ?