# Problem with Google Apps email/smtp to send mails from website

Tags: asp.net, email, web-config, smtp, gmail

I have an Asp.Net site which uses google SMTP to send emails.. its working fine with normal gmail accounts using the below configuration

```
<smtp from="myname@gmail.com">
<network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="myname@gmail.com" password="mypassword" enableSsl="true" /></smtp>
```

Now I need to use Google Apps email and smtp and I tried to change the configuration as shown below

```
<smtp from="myname@mydomain.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="myname@mydomain.com" password="mypassword" enableSsl="true" /> </smtp>
```

But its throwing the Authentication failed error!!!
"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"

I double checked the Google EMail Settings, Username and password but still couldn't solve it!!

Any thoughts on the issue will be a great help..

Thanks and Regards,
Anz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN :

> Some SMTP servers require that the
>   client be authenticated before the
>   server sends e-mail on its behalf. Set
>   this property to true when this
>   SmtpClient object should authenticate
>   using the default credentials of the
>   currently logged on user. If the
>   UseDefaultCredentials property is set
>   to false, then the value set in the
>   Credentials property will be used for
>   the credentials when connecting to the
>   server.

---

```
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }; 

    smtp.Send(mail);
```

Look to this link [also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704636/418343).

Comment: thanks for the reply.. one tip from your code snipplet solved the issue :)  
just wanted to add defaultCredentials="false" in the web.config..   

not sure why its not needed when sending from free gmail acct!!

Comment: How to set the ServicePointManager setting in vb.net??? i dont get delegate in it???

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the instructions in the server response (if any).  Probably, you need more/another authentication scheme than the usual username/password pattern. Maybe you find more answers in the google API documentation?