# After publishing ASP.NET website on server smtp Email is not sent.... What could be the problem?

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, smtp, gmail

I have written code to send Email in ASP.NET with VB language. I have tested it on local host and my email is working. I am using Gmail settings for sending email with smtp.gmail.com and 587 port number. But when i have published the website Email is not sent. What could be the problem?? will it be a server problem??

**EDIT**
[Problem with Google Apps email/smtp to send mails from website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262242/problem-with-google-apps-email-smtp-to-send-mails-from-website)
as given in this link i have tried below code

```
Public Class clsSSL
    Public Function AcceptAllCertifications(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal certification As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate, ByVal chain As System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain, ByVal sslPolicyErrors As System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

new class in same vb file which i called it as below... this works well on  local host..

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf New clsSSL().AcceptAllCertifications
```

But i got security exception as below

```
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

What could be the solution

**EDIT 2**

I have shared hosting on godaddy.com. Can i change some setting regarding smtp.gmail.com  or port number in that account??? I dont exactly know how to change settings...

Comment: Do you have access to the live server?

Comment: No, i dont have access to server... Can i do programatically anything???   i have seen 1 previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262242/problem-with-google-apps-email-smtp-to-send-mails-from-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a firewall issue on the live server. Try looking at what ports are blocked.

Comment: I do not have access to server...  Will this be useful to set some certificate issues... But this code is in C# so what could be vb code for the same... because delegate in this case is not working ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

Comment: You don't actually need the ServerCertificateValidationCallback. Try it without that line. You can also ask your service provider if they are blocking that port.

Comment: Also, try the following defaultCredentials="false" in the web.config

Comment: in vb file i have already set default credentials = false.. should i also do that in web.config...?? well m try that also...

Comment: I should have to consider this as true answer as the Problem is from live server only...... Thanx