# Send Mail with C#

Tags: c#, .net, email

despite all the topics about this on Stackoverflow. I can't manage to find the solution of this problem:

i have this exception :

> SMTP server needs a secure connection or the client is not
>   authentificated. Reply from the server is : 5.5.1 Authentication
>   Required. Learn more at

using this code:

```
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress(user.Email, "From Name");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("myadress@gmail.com", "To Name");
    const string fromPassword = "fromPassword";
    const string subject = "Subject";
    const string body = "Body";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
        Timeout = 20000
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
```

What am i missing please?
thanks for your help

Comment: This was asked and answered on SO before - did you search before asking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp

Comment: Check out the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp

Comment: Check your password and ensure it is a strong one, as far as Google is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything. I suspect you got your password wrong. You didn't forget to change it from "fromPassword" to what it really should be did you?

[This is a cleaner implementation of the same task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me

```
  SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
  NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("username","password");
  //username doesn't include @gmail.com         
   sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   sc.Credentials = nc;
   sc.EnableSsl = true;
   sc.Port = 587;
     try
      {
       sc.Send(mm);
      } 
     catch (Exception ex)
      {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Error Sending", EventLogEntryType.Error);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you have typed your password incorrectly or (more likely) you are trying to use your normal password after you have enabled Google's [2-Step Authentication](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=180744&topic=1099588&ctx=topic)

You need to generate and use an [application specific password](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833)