# Add multiple images in the email body (inline)using c# windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I searched for this several times and found solutions,but all supports only one image.Finally I used this code.
But  the problem is,if the html contain more than one image only one image is shown in the body and the others will come as attachment.

```
string inputHtmlContent = htmlbody;
string outputHtmlContent = string.Empty;
var myResources = new List<LinkedResource>();

if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputHtmlContent)))
{
  var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
  doc.LoadHtml(inputHtmlContent);
  HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
  if (nodes !=null)
  {
    foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
    {
      if (node.Attributes.Contains("src"))
      {
        string data = node.Attributes["src"].Value;
        string imgPath = Application.StartupPath+"\\"+data;
        var imgLogo = new LinkedResource(imgPath);
        imgLogo.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        imgLogo.ContentType = new ContentType("image/jpeg");
        myResources.Add(imgLogo);
        node.Attributes["src"].Value = string.Format("cid:{0}", imgLogo.ContentId);
        outputHtmlContent = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    outputHtmlContent = inputHtmlContent;
  }
  AlternateView av2 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(outputHtmlContent,
                            null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
  foreach (LinkedResource linkedResource in myResources)
  {
    av2.LinkedResources.Add(linkedResource);
  }

  msg.AlternateViews.Add(av2);
```

Please help me to resolve this,How to show all images inside email body?...

Answer (score 4):

You can attach images to mail and then put `img` tag and use[`ContentId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.attachment.contentid(v=exchg.80).aspx) of attachment as `src` this way:

```
private void denMailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string subject = "Subject";
    string body = @"Image 1: <img src=""$CONTENTID1$""/> <br/> Image 2: <img src=""$CONTENTID2$""/> <br/> Some Other Content";

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("from@example.com");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@example.com"));
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

    string contentID1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
    string contentID2 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");

    body = body.Replace("$CONTENTID1$", "cid:" + contentID1);
    body = body.Replace("$CONTENTID2$", "cid:" + contentID2);

    AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");

    //path of image or stream
    LinkedResource imagelink1 = new LinkedResource(@"D:\1.png", "image/png");
    imagelink1.ContentId = contentID1;
    imagelink1.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink1);

    LinkedResource imagelink2 = new LinkedResource(@"D:\2.png", "image/png");
    imagelink2.ContentId = contentID2;
    imagelink2.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
    htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink2);

    mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Host = "mail.example.com";
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from@example.com", "password");
    client.Send(mail);
}
```

And here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This will help to add only one image,my problem is how to add multiple imagws

Comment: You can simply add multiple liked resource.

Comment: That I shown in above code,but problem is it only display first image,others come as attachment.

Comment: @sayana Check the edit, it works properly with multiple images too, to test, just copy it and paste into your code and use correct addresses and credentials and see the result.

Comment: Thanks I saw it,but how to write it in a loop.I have many images.

Comment: It's completely related to the structure of your template, but if you look at the code carefully, you will see a repetitive pattern in the code.

Comment: please look at my sample code ,I added multiple linked resources using list.But that's not working,only first image is displayed ,others come as attachment.Please correct it.

Comment: I believe your case is a specific case using `HtmlAgilityPack` and a dynamic template while my answer is a general answer and this way it will be more useful for future readers. Any way Let me know if you could use a loop, otherwise share your template structure and I'll help you to solve your problem :) +1 for your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This will generate attachment for excel , csv , pdf and also inline attachment i.e. in the body of email for png format of image. **For png format multiple image will get embedded inline one after other by *GetEmbeddedImage* method**. You can customize it based on your requirement.

```
SmtpClient smtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtpServerName);
smtpServer.Port = 25;
smtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
//smtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
MailMessage smtpEmail = new MailMessage();
string messageBodyImage = @"<img width=1200 id=""MyContent"" src=""cid:{0}"">";
 toAddressList = toAddress.Split(';');
foreach (string toEmail in toAddressList)
    smtpEmail.To.Add(toEmail);

smtpEmail.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
smtpEmail.Body = messageBody;
smtpEmail.Subject = subject;
foreach (string format in fileExtension)
 {    
    switch (format)
     {       
    case "PNG": 
    smtpEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    smtpEmail.AlternateViews.Add(GetEmbeddedImage(reportByteStream, messageBodyImage, format)); 
    break;
    case "CSV":      
    smtpEmail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(new MemoryStream(myStream[format][0]), "MyReport." + format, "text/csv"));  
    break;
    case "XLS": 
    smtpEmail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(new MemoryStream(myStream[format][0]), "MyReport." + format, "application/vnd.ms-excel"));
    break;
    default: // For PDF
    smtpEmail.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(new MemoryStream(myStream[format][0]), "MyReport." + format, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf));
    break;
    }
}
```

Method to embed multiple image inline.

```
    private AlternateView GetEmbeddedImage(Dictionary<string, Byte[][]> streamAttachment, string msgTemplate, string fileFormat)
    {
        LinkedResource imageFile = null;
        AlternateView alternateView = null;
        string msgBody = string.Empty;
        try
        {
        List<LinkedResource> imageFiles = new List<LinkedResource>();
        for (int page = 0; page < streamAttachment[fileFormat].Length; page++)
        {   
                imageFile = new LinkedResource(new MemoryStream(streamAttachment[fileFormat][page]));
                imageFile.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                msgBody = msgBody + "<BR/>" + string.Format(msgTemplate, imageFile.ContentId);
                imageFiles.Add(imageFile); 
        }

        alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(msgBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
        imageFiles.ForEach(img => alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(img));
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }
        return alternateView;
    }
```