# Error in C#: The type or namespace 'SmptMailMessage' could not be found

Tags: c#, smtp

Well, I've done my homework, even looked at several examples on this very website, to no avail. My program is meant to send the data filled out on the Form, and send it to an email. The rest of my code shows no errors, except for the SmptMailMessage one. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace FPSArrestReport
 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SmtpClient SmptMailMessage = new SmtpClient();
        SmptMailMessage mail = new SmtpMailMessage("smtp.gmail.com", 25); // error on this line
         \\on the SmptMailmessage

           //set the to address to the primary email 
      mail.To.Add("xxx@abc.com"); 

     //set the message type and subject and body 
      mail.IsHtmlMessage = true; 
      mail.Subject = ""; 
      mail.Body = "Hello world!"; 

    //send the email 
      mail.Send();   
      }
```

Comment: When you consistently use `Smtp` instead of `Smpt`, many of your problems will go away.

Comment: Noob here: How do you call this function from a cshtml page?

Comment: Lol, @spender. I noticed I was using stmp xD

Answer (score 5):

There is no such Type as SmtpMailMessage (or SmptMailMessage for that matter) in the System.Net.Mail library. It looks like you are trying to create an instance of SmtpClient to send a message. Perhaps you mean to do something like;

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25); 

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add("xxx@abc.com");
client.Send(mail);
```

You are using 2 objects here - an SmtpMailClient (to do the sending) and a **MailMessage** which describes the message.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however, when I do what you have posted above, an error shows up for the IsHtmlTrue shows up. Anyway to fix this? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: There's no such property on MailMessage. Perhaps you want .IsBodyHtml = true

Comment: Thanks everyone.. but now, ANOTHER error: When I try to add the mail.from.Address, it gives me an error: non-invocable member System.Net.MailAddress.Address cannnot be used like a method. Sorry for asking so much.

Comment: You need to do some more of your own research and learning - this isn't a line-by-line code walkthrourgh.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `StmpMailMessage` class in .NET. You want `MailMessage`. You also want to pass the  server credentials to `SmtpClient`.

This question here explains how to do it with Gmail.

[Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)

Comment: How do I pass server credentials to SmtpClient? Sorry, I'm new to C#.

Comment: @user1713246 have a look at the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a simple fix for you.  Also, try to watch that your spelling everything correctly. :D

```
    $
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Net;
    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("YourEmailAcct@gmail.com", "NameForIt");
            MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("DesinationEmailAddress", "NameForDestination");
            const string fromPassword = "password";
            const string subject = "Subject";
            const string body = "First line of text \n Second line of text.";

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
                {
                    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
                };

                try
                {
                    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                    {
                        Subject = subject,
                        Body = body
                    };

                    client.Send(message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There was an error!" + ex.Message);
                }


            }

            }
        }
```

Comment: RE: "Also, try to watch that your spelling everything correctly.".... such as "you're" and not "your" ? ;-)