# gmail-api .net How to MVC website send email without logging in

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, email, gmail-api

I try to use google gmail-api on a .NET MVC5 website on azure. I bought a gmail suite account and would like that my websites send email through gmail.

I followed more or less the tutorial and the code below is the result of my exploration. It's work but... a google authentification windows open each time.
It's look like the ClientId and ClientSecret are not enough.

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                    ClientSecret = "xxxxxx"
                },
                new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailModify },
                _defaultSender,
                CancellationToken.None);

            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "MyProjet"
            });

            var msg = new AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = html,
                ContentType = "text/html",
                From = new MailAddress(_defaultSender)
            };

            foreach (var recipient in recipients)
            {
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));
            }
            var msgStr = new StringWriter();
            msg.Save(msgStr);

            await service.Users.Messages.Send(new Message()
            {
                Raw = Base64UrlEncode(msgStr.ToString())
            }, "me").ExecuteAsync();
```

The google [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) wrote:

> The sample will attempt to open a new window or tab in your default browser. If this fails, copy the URL from the console and manually open it in your browser.

There isn't any other way? A website service account can not send contact/loggin/etc emails via gmail?
The other stacks show that it may seem that way:
[Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)
or [How to send an email in .Net according to new security policies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851484/how-to-send-an-email-in-net-according-to-new-security-policies/34917400#34917400)

Comment: Does [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications ](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) help?  It sounds like you're using a standard credential, which is going to prompt for username/password.  You need to be using a service credential instead, which will use an alternate auth flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brendan Green](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1567352/brendan-green) put me in the right direction. I confuse gmail impersonation account (where the tutorial leads) and using a service account for the send as a predefine email.

Here a code sample that works a MVC5 WebApp on Azure.
Goodbye sendgrid! Hello GMAIL!

```
var serviceAccountEmail = "myserviceaccount@domain-xxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(Resources.Gmail.Certificat,//the google .p12 file stored as resource
                "notasecret",
                X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
                {
                    User = "emailYouWanToUse@domain.com",
                    Scopes = new[] { "https://mail.google.com/" }
                }.FromCertificate(certificate)
            );

            // Create the service.
            var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "ProjectName"
            });

            var msg = new AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = html,
                ContentType = "text/html",
                From = new MailAddress(_defaultSender)
            };

            foreach (var recipient in recipients)
            {
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));
            }
            var msgStr = new StringWriter();
            msg.Save(msgStr);

            await service.Users.Messages.Send(new Message()
            {
                Raw = Base64UrlEncode(msgStr.ToString())
            }, "me").ExecuteAsync();
```