# Failure sending mail - c# - godaddy

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I'm trying to send email using the following code. It is hosted in godaddy.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com");
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
mail.Subject = "Test email";
string body;
using (var sr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Template/") + "Email.html"))
{
    body = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
string messageBody = string.Format(body, name, expDate);
mail.Body = messageBody;
Attachment doc = new Attachment(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/class_3b.pdf"));
mail.Attachments.Add(doc);
client.Send(mail);
```

But I'm getting error:

> {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond 74.125.130.109:25    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)}

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code while running locally?

Comment: `MailMessage`, `SmtpClient`, and `Attachment` all implement the `IDisposable` interface and should be wrapped in `using` statements much like how you have your `StreamReader` in the middle.

Comment: Do you really try to send an email via Google´s SMTP server without any authentication? Or is this just sample data and your real SMTP-Server is not reachable via internet? This would be a spammer´s dream.

Comment: I'm trying to to send an email via Google´s SMTP server without any authentication. Any issues?

Comment: @Jobi Well for one without authentication it will not work. Google is not going to let unauthorized accounts to just send emails.

Comment: @Jobi Gmail won't let you send email without authentication.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this is not needed, as Google is sending the mail, not GoDaddy's SMTP server.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465096/how-to-send-an-e-mail-with-c-sharp-through-gmail

Comment: two things, you need authentication as others have said, second you need to enable SSL in your code

Comment: @GeorgeChond Thanks, it seemed a bit much. I edited my comment accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate. See [Send Email via C# through Google Apps account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757987/send-email-via-c-sharp-through-google-apps-account) for example. Google even check that the authentication address and the "from" address corresponds...

Answer (score -1):

To send mail using System.Net.Mail, you need to configure your SMTP service in your application's `web.config` file using these values for `mailSettings:`

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="your email address">
        <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" userName="your email address" password="******" defaultCredentials="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Code Behind:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From = new MailAddress("your email address");

message.To.Add(new MailAddress("your recipient"));

message.Subject = "your subject";
message.Body = "content of your email";

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(message);
```