# How do I send an email from my C# windows application?

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

I.m working on a Windows app where the user has to enter a password. I also have a "Forgot Password" link. on the window. When that's clicked, I have the user enter their email address and click a Submit button. Every time they enter an email address and click the button, I get the error message:

> SmtpException has occured: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.

The code I'm using is:

```
try
{
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

    MailAddress from = new MailAddress("bgatt64@gmail.com", "Bob Gatto");
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress("bgatto64@yahoo.com", "Bob Gatto");

    MailMessage eMsg = new MailMessage(from, to);
    eMsg.Subject = "Your Password Renewal Request";
    eMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    eMsg.Body = "This is the body.";

    SmtpClient eClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    eClient.EnableSsl = true;
    eClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;gmail

    // The following email and password used is that of my own gmail email
    // that I use for my own personal email.

    eClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("<MyOwnEmail@gmail.com>", "<MyPassword>");
    eClient.Send(eMsg);
}
catch (SmtpException ex)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("SmtpException has occurred: " + ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

What else needs to be done?

Comment: As an aside... `throw ex;` is an anti-pattern.  It strips useful information from the exception before re-throwing it.  To re-throw the original exception just use `throw;`  Or remove that `catch` block entirely since it isn't doing anything.

Comment: Try port 465.  From docs: `In the Port field, enter one of the following numbers:  For SSL, enter 465.  For TLS, enter 587.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an e-mail with C# through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29465096/how-to-send-an-e-mail-with-c-sharp-through-gmail)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use your plain google account password to authenticate to Gmail SMTP server anymore as Google requires two-step authentication now.
You'll need to use the [App Password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) instead:

- Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security and turn on **Two Step** verification
- Click "App Passwords"
- Request a new password for the **Mail** application on the **Windows Computer**

[image]

You'll get the string with the 4 groups of characters. Now you need to use it in your code:

```
eClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("<MyOwnEmail@gmail.com>", "<App Password>");
```

You can find more info [Here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use your Gmail account for email sending. You can try to use AWS Simple Email Service. It has 62000 free outgoing emails per month - https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/?nc1=h_ls Or maybe you can look at the SendGrid service - https://sendgrid.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

After the removal of less secure apps you can no longer use your actual google password to connect to the smpt server you need to create an apps password.

[How to create a Apps Password for connecting to Google's SMTP server.](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/IGOt3zo98Xw)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace GmailSmtpConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string To = "[redacted]@gmail.com";
        private const string From = "[redacted]@gmail.com";
        
        private const string GoogleAppPassword = "";
        
        private const string Subject = "Test email";
        private const string Body = "<h1>Hello</h1>";
        
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            {
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(From , GoogleAppPassword),
                EnableSsl = true,
            };
            var mailMessage = new MailMessage
            {
                From = new MailAddress(From),
                Subject = Subject,
                Body = Body,
                IsBodyHtml = true,
            };
            mailMessage.To.Add(To);

            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: if you are trying to connect users then you could also use Xoauth2 but using an apps password is far easer solution.