# SQL Server 2012 SSIS Script Task for sending mail from Gamil to Gmail , showing "DTS Script :Runtime Error"

Tags: sql-server, email, ssis, ssis-2012, script-task

I am using SSIS 12, SQL Server 2012, Visual Studio 2012 and .net 4.

My SSIS script task code(for sending mail):

```
// Introduction to the script task
/* The Script Task allows you to perform virtually any operation that can be accomplished in
 * a .Net application within the context of an Integration Services control flow. 
 * 
 * Expand the other regions which have "Help" prefixes for examples of specific ways to use
 * Integration Services features within this script task. */

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace ST_20fdf0b00e2949fda158e6680c127473
{
        public void Main()
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("raihanuahmed@gmail.com", "password");

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("raihanuahmed@gmail.com");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("raihan.csse.aiub@gmail.com"));
            msg.Subject = "AW2012 ETL Process Complite";
            msg.Body = string.Format("{0} records loaded into DimProduct", 0);

            smtp.Send(msg);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
    }
}
```

After executing this email sending script, I am always getting

> "DTS Script :Runtime Error"
>
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()

I have uploaded my problem into Youtube here is the link:

[DTS Script :Runtime Error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMpLsSoW4WU&feature=youtu.be)

Here is my project link in Dropbox:

[EmailScript](http://dropbox.com/s/o0jb4u8ch75hv7v/ScriptTask.rar?dl=0)

Comment: First comment out lines until you work out which line is throwing the runtime error.

Comment: Sorry, cant able to trace it , but i have uploaded my problem in Youtube here is the link :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMpLsSoW4WU&feature=youtu.be
and here is my project link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/o0jb4u8ch75hv7v/ScriptTask.rar?dl=0

Comment: comment out `smtp.Send(msg);`. Do you still get the error?

Comment: This describes how to set a breakpoint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms140033(v=sql.110).aspx you need to set a breakpoint, step through the code and find a more useful error. "Runtime error" is not useful but if you capture the error while it's running you can usually drill in and get a useful error.

Comment: OMG !!!! ,, if i comment out smtp.Send(msg);  ,, I do not get any error ...
But my problem isn't fixed yet as i cant able to receive the message

Comment: Warning: 0x0 at Task Succesful Email: Cannot attach the  VSTA debugger. Re-starting the debugging may resolve the problem.
Error: 0x1 at Task Succesful Email: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Task failed: Task Succesful Email

Comment: You need a more detailed error message but it looks like debugging won't help. Uncomment `smtp.Send(msg);` and add this after it: `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }`. If this is valid code (not  sure) it should pop up a more detailed error message

Comment: and something to consider... do you have an internal email server? because you might have more luck sending email to that.

Comment: thank you for your replay, 
when i use try-catch , a window pop us say **the smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. the server response was: 5.5.1 authentication required**

Comment: But interesting thing is at the same time i have revived an email which subject is **Sign-in attempt prevented** and in body it say **Hi Raihan Uddin,
Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account raihanuahmed@gmail.com from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.We strongly recommend that you use a secure app, like Gmail, to access your account. All apps made by Google meet these security standards. Using a less secure app, on the other hand, could leave your account vulnerable. Google stopped this sign-in attempt, but you should review your recently used devices:**

Comment: I searched your error message and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated which says to log in to gmail and _enable Less Secure Sign-In in your google account_. Try that

Comment: "sorry ,I do not have an internal email server" :( :( :(  i am just using Gmail

Comment: Here is the video shot of the current condition of my problem (after using try catch): [After try catch SSIS Script Task for sending mail Problem]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CExG8CvUD2Q&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution :) Many Many thanks to Mr.Nick.McDermaid ......
 solution is :

Change account access for less secure apps https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: The try/catch is just to get a more useful error. You need to take this out before you deploy your package or it's going to pop up messageboxes and freeze.