# sending email from smtp gmail in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

i am trying to send email from my web app. i am using `smtp gmail` for the same. but for some reasons i am not able to send a mail.. i have tried port numbers like 25,465,587 but none of these are working....

```
public static void SendMail(string host, string senderName, string frmAddress, string toAddress, int port, string subject, string messageText)
    {
        String smtpHost, port1;

        smtpHost = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtphost"].ToString();
        port1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpport"].ToString();

        SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, Convert.ToInt16(port1));
        mailClient.EnableSsl = true;


        NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential();
        cred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString();
        cred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"].ToString();
        mailClient.Credentials = cred;

        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        //mailClient.Credentials = cred;

        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        try
        {
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(frmAddress, senderName);
            message.From = fromAddress;

            message.To.Add(toAddress);
            message.Subject = subject;

            message.IsBodyHtml = false;
            message.Body = messageText;

            mailClient.Send(message);
            //Response.Write("<script  language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.alert('Email Successfully Sent.');</script>");
        }
        catch
        {
            //Response.Write("<script  language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>window.alert('Send Email Failed '" + ex.Message + ");</script>");
        }
    }
```

calling this method:

```
protected void btnMail_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string from = txtEmail.Text;
        string to = "my gmail id";
        string message = taMessage.InnerText;

        Global.SendMail(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtphost"].ToString(), txtName.Text, from, to, Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpport"]), "Enquiry", taMessage.InnerText);
    }
```

web.config settings :

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="smtphost" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
    <!--<add key="smtphost" value="103.231.41.229"/>-->
    <add key="smtpport" value="587"/>
    <!--<add key="port" value="25"/>-->
    <add key="username" value="my gmail id/>
    <add key="password" value="my password"/>
    <add key="From" value="my gmail id"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Exception : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906077/gmail-error-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp

Comment: Did you tried `client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;`  see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a security issue, Gmail by default prevents access for your mail account from custom applications. You can set it up to accept the login from your application.
[image]
After Logging in to your mail ,

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

### Update:

```
 msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: this and  message.IsBodyHtml = true .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // body
        //subject
        //reciever id

        sendmail(recieverID, subject, body);
    }
```

method for sending mail

```
protected void sendmail(string reciever, string subject, string body)
    {
        string senderID = "sender email id";
        string pwd = "password ";
        string result = "Message Sent Successfully";
        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, pwd),
                Timeout = 30000
            };
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(senderID, reciever, subject, body);
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtpClient.Send(msg);
        }
        catch
        {
            result = "Error Sending Mail";
        }
       Response.Write(result );
    }
```

OR

U can also go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated)