# The SMTP Server requires a secure connection. 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

Tags: c#, email, model-view-controller, smtp

Good day,

I have a MVC application that send out emails, everything works fine locally, however when deploy the code to Windows Server 2012 with IIS8 it throws error above. I have seen some answers with related postrs, however it doesnt seem to work for me. What I tried was this.UseDefaultCredentials = true; as suggested by many but doesnt work for me. Please see my code below.

```
public class EMMEmailService : SmtpClient
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public EMMEmailService() :
        base(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmmEmailHost"], Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMMPort"]))    
        {
            //Get values from web.config file:
            this.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMMUserName"];
            this.EnableSsl = false;//Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMMSsl"]);
            //this.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            this.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMMUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EMMPassword"]);
        }

    }
```

and here is the config file

```
    <!--Smptp Server (confirmations emails)-->
<add key="EMMUserName" value="business@xxxxxx"/>
<add key="EMMPassword" value="xxxxxxxxx"/>
<add key="EmmEmailHost" value="x.x.x.x"/>
<add key="EMMPort" value="25"/>
<add key="EMMSsl" value="true"/>
```

Please assist as I am stuck with this error.

Comment: are you sure the username youve supplied is the correct one?  its less common that port 25 is ssl..  If you're getting not authenticated you made connection which is  a good start.

Comment: @Filburt How can I go about fixing this?....

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, it is correct,It workf perfect on my local machine, only fails with authentication when I run it on the server.

Comment: Are you sure its picking up the right config file?

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, there is only one config file in my deployed website.

Comment: And what is your smtp server (for examle, gmail)?

Comment: This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27896975/8280352) his solved my issue!