# Windows Powershell SMTP server requires a secure connection

Tags: windows, powershell

I get the error:

> Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
>   At C:\documents\yes.ps1:22 char:1
>   + Send-MailMessage @EmailSplat
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:   (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpExcept
>      ion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

```
$MyEmail = "****@gmail.com"
$SMTP= "smtp.gmail.com"
$To = "****@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Attachments"
$Body = "Here's the attachment"
$Creds = (Get-Credential -Credential "$MyEmail")
$env:localappdata

Start-Sleep 2
$Attachments = get-childitem "$env:******" | select-object -ExpandProperty FullName
$EmailSplat = @{To = $to
                From = $MyEmail
                Attachments = $Attachments
                Subject = $Subject
                Body = $Body
                SmtpServer = $SMTP
                Credential = $Creds
                UseSsl = $True
                Port = 587
                DeliveryNotificationOption = 'never'
                }
Send-MailMessage @EmailSplat
```

Comment: Try to format the error message: 1) paste 2) a) mark b) use "the `“ ”`-button" to turn into a block quote 3) Append two blanks to each line that shall be followed by a line break.

Comment: Since you are using gmail, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25215834/517852) seems relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable **Allow less secure apps** in your google account because Google may block sign in attempts from some apps (or devices) that don't use modern security standards.

Sign into google account, and after that, go to:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

And enable the *Allow less secure apps* option.

[image: Enable less secure apps option]

Answer (score 1):

The step without which this won't work is : ***App Password***

---

After **Allow less secure apps**, I was still facing the same issue because google recently updated its authentication mechanism. Here are the steps

1. Make Sure the account from which you're trying to send mail has ***Two Factor Authentication*** enabled and it has also ***Allow less secure apps*** enabled.
2. If you're successful with step 1, You will be able to see ***App Passwords*** options.
3. Just select the appropriate option where you want to use your google account.

For the OP, My images shows what you need.

[After Enabling Two Factor Authentication this is what should be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM8ae.png)

[After creating app password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppIv8.png)