# Gmail SMTP Access 5.5.1 Authentication Required. From Custom Domain

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send emails via `smtp.gmail.com` in the standard way, and I'm getting a standard error, but for some ***non-standard*** reason.

Specifically, I get this error: `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.` when I send the mail.

The answers on this link have not helped me: [The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503333/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated/18503540)

I suspect that there are *additional* steps required if you're trying to do this ***from a custom domain***.

I've created a throw-away standard Gmail account to test out my code and everything works perfectly there.

- If I en-/dis-able *Less Secure Apps* then it behaves as you'd expect, and as per the linked solutions.
- If I en-/dis-able *2FA* and create 3rd party app passwords then, again, it behaves as I'd expect, and as per the linked solutions.

So my code, and my ability to configure a general Gamil acccount, are working just fine.

But when I use an otherwise identical GSuite email address, set up on a custom domain (`system@clientdomain.co.uk`) then nothing works :( I've tried all the permutations, with/without *LessSecureApps*, with main user password / with 3rd Party App Password, etc. Nothing works.

I can only assume that either the custom domain or the fact that it's a GSuite account is breaking it.

What now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I either needed to wait longer, or change the settings ***harder!!***

A colleague wandered past and asked what the problem was and I demonstrated it, including going through and setting the settings again, and this time it worked. I'm 80% sure they were the same settings, but perhaps not?