# SMTP Server Error

Tags: c#, smtp

I've been making a Real Time Modding Tool for Call of Duty and am trying to make a report bug system, but I'm getting this error:

[image]

the codes that I'm using for this are as follows:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the mail message
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    // Set The Addresses
    mail.From = new MailAddress("brinkerzbhtests@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("brinkerzbhtests@gmail.com");

    // Login to that email

    // Set The Content
    mail.Subject = "RTM Tool Bug";
    mail.Body = textBox1.Text;

    // Send The Message
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    NetworkCredential info = new NetworkCredential("brinkerzbhtests@gmail.com", "PasswordNotBeingGivenHere");
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

    try
    {
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Picture of full help screen:

[image]

Comment: cant get to your screenshots, server is down

Comment: Check out this question and correct answer for a code sample:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

```
NetworkCredential info = new NetworkCredential("brinkerzbhtests@gmail.com", "PasswordNotBeingGivenHere");
smtp.Credentials  =info ; // add this line
```

Answer (score 0):

You create your network credentials and don't associate them with the smtp client.

Try adding the line:
`smtp.Credentials = Info;`