# sending email failed in .net when using google smtp server

Tags: c#, email, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I am trying to send email like this

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("fromaddress", "From Name");
        var toAddress = new MailAddress("toaddress", "To Name");
        const string fromPassword = "password";
        const string subject = "Subject";
        const string body = "Body";

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

but it gives this error .

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. 
The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
```

I am sing this code in simple console application on my local host . So whats the issue in my code ?

**Update**

I changed fromAddress email and it send email successfully . But i don't receive any email in my toAddress email's inbox/Spam .

Comment: Why are C# 4, 3, 2 all tagged?

Comment: Are you sure that the username/password combination does indeed work? I see that your implementation is the same as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail).

Comment: Have you tried port 465?

Comment: @HOKBONG Yes , when we try this port it simply stuck for few minutes and then timeout

Comment: It can be a firewall problem. If you have access to that, open port 587 and 465 for outbound connection.

Comment: Well there is no firewall here . There might be some other problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to add DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network when creating SmtpClient.

See post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/489594/1432770

There is a variety of reasons for this discussed here:
[Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)

Your code in the first link has worked for me.

Comment: if you see my question . I do have this

Comment: yeah but i searched alot and almost tries all of them . Thats why i came here to ask

Comment: Even the application specific password explained in the post? (Direct link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/9572958/1432770)

Answer (score 0):

Do you use two steps verification?
You need to sign in using application-specific passwords: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

Your code worked for me too!