# Password Recovery in asp.net The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, authentication

I am using Default asp.net membership for user log in, register system. I am going to implement Password recovery option in my web application. I am developing my application in home and using default localhost server.

I made a RecoverPassword.aspx page here is its code:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RecoverPassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="myshop.Account.RecoverPassword" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:PasswordRecovery ID="RecoverPwd" runat="server"></asp:PasswordRecovery>
</asp:Content>
```

I then edit my web.config file here is code:

```
<system.net> 
  <mailSettings> 
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="mymail@gmail.com">
       <network
          host="smtp.gmail.com"
          port="587"  
          enableSsl="true"
          password="mypassword"
          userName="mymail@gmail.com"
          defaultCredentials="true"/> 
    </smtp> 
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

After saving when I run my PasswordRecover.aspx page and I give the user name in text box and hit the submit button I get following error.

The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

I did not know where is the problem I not get any email on my gmail account please help

Comment: Try `defaultCredentials="false"`

Comment: rene not working problem still exist :(

Comment: Anything in these answers that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set "enable ssl" property to true in your code

```
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: In where I enable this property? in web.config file I already enable this to true ..

Comment: Yes it is already in the connfig, but I think you should add it in your code too.

Comment: You really should explain in what situation this is needed because without that this doesn;t make sense

Comment: Sargis you said right but look at my whole code and tell me where I placed this code too ?

Comment: AFAIK this property can only be set in code and cannot be specified in the config file. Sameer you must place that code in your c# code.

Comment: using System.Net.Mail;

namespace myshop.Account
{
    public partial class RecoverPassword : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.EnableSsl = true;
        }
    }
}

Comment: problem still exist :(

Comment: Try to  set UseDefaultCredentials to false.
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;