# sending email using gmail from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

I am trying to send mail using gmail in asp.net

My Code:

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(txtEmail.Text, txtTo.Text))
        {
            mm.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
            mm.Body = txtBody.Text;
            if (fuAttachment.HasFile)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);
                mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
            }
            mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential(txtEmail.Text, txtPassword.Text);
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
        }
```

But i am getting error:

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
```

where is my error?

Comment: should the port be 465 ?

Comment: Use `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false`

Comment: Its not sending its showing The operation has timed out.

Comment: if i change to smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false its showing same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below suggestions:

1. Try setting "UseDefaultCredentials" to "False"  `smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;`
2. Try logging to your Gmail account, it may be blocking the access.
3. Try enabling access to your Gmail account, see this link for more information http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/How-To-Unlock-Gmail-For-A-New-Email-Program-Or-Service.htm

Comment: Are you running this code from your local machine ?

Comment: Try checking out your password it may be considered too weak, if so try changing it to see if it will help. see this link for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Change "smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;" to "smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;". Or test your gmail account with code below.

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(new MailAddress("sender@example.com"), new MailAddress("recipient@example.com")))
        {
            mm.Subject = "test";
            mm.Body = "body test";

            mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("sender@example.com", "password");
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Send(mm);

        }
```

**UPDATE**

Go to: google.com/settings/security?hl=en_GB and if field "Access for less secure apps" is Disabled click settings and change it to enabled... Then test your connection with code above. It worked for me on new gmail user

Comment: Ok i think i resolved your problem: 
Go to: https://www.google.com/settings/security?hl=en_GB
And if field "Access for less secure apps" is Disabled click settings and change it to enabled...