# Server Connection using SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send a default passwords using smtp for users who want to retrieve their new passwords!

My Code :

```
public void SendUserPass()
{
    string sql = "Select Username, Password from Registration 
                  where Email='" + Email +   "'";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table = db.RunQuery(sql);

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage("Esco@gmail.com", Email);
    message.Subject = "ESCO -Forgot Password";
    message.Body = "Username " + table.Rows[0][0].ToString() + "<br/> Password" +  
    table.Rows[0][1].ToString(); 

    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Esco@gmail.com", "Mypassword");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

I get this error :

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at....
>
> ```
>           Line 310:            smtp.Send(message);
> ```

Any help please ?

Comment: Mandatory question: are you **absolutely sure** the login/password are correct? Have you verified that?

Comment: Set it off but had the same error !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Please do not deface your posts. The code and error message provide important context here.

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me**

Login in to gmail ( in your case it is Esco@gmail.com)

visit

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Enable access to less secure apps

Comment: I got this error message :The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Comment: You have to enable ssl

smtp.EnableSsl = true

Please mark this as Answer if your issue is resolved

Comment: Its already been enabled? Could it been cause I send from gmail to yahoo account?

Comment: That should not make any difference. Can you please post the latest code?