# SmtpException was caught when sending mail

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com", "SMTP Test");
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com"));
            mail.Subject = "Subject test";
            mail.Body = "Body test";
            client.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("mail send.");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I get this error:

I cant upload images yet so i use puush.

http://puu.sh/fpAnF/d4372b0b55.png

Error a bit translated:

> Error when sending e-mail. system.net.mail.smtpexception: error when
>   sending e-mail. ---> system.net.webexception: can't connect to the
>   external server ---> system.net.sockets.sochetexception: can't connect
>   because the goalcomputer (dont know the exact translation of that) the
>   connection actively has refused.

can somobody please help me?

Comment: Here, have a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp.

Works for me

Comment: @TomerKlein doesn't work for me :(

Comment: try running this command:
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 from CMD window.
and let me know the result

Comment: @TomerKlein http://puu.sh/fpBMx/305f30cc11.png translated: telnet isn't recognized as an internal, or external command, program or bachfile.

Comment: if you are working with windows 7 or 8 you have to install telnet client
From add/remove windows features.
you can try connect to your account using outlook,
it will help you to understand is the problem is in your code,

Comment: @TomerKlein My colleague solved it. I tried another port. Thank you for your help. Appreciate it.