# I am trying to retrieve my password using email in ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Problem, when i m sending a mail through this code then error is occured that "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. "

my  coding is :

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string UniqueCode = string.Empty;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        // get the records matching the supplied username or email id.         
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from registration where username COLLATE Latin1_general_CS_AS=@username or email COLLATE Latin1_general_CS_AS=@emailId", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Convert.ToString(txtUserName.Text.Trim()));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailId", Convert.ToString(txtEmailId.Text.Trim()));
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmd.Dispose();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Read();
            //generate unique code
            UniqueCode = Convert.ToString(System.Guid.NewGuid());
            //Updating an unique random code in then UniquCode field of the database table
            cmd = new SqlCommand("update registration set UniqueCode=@uniqueCode where username=@username or email=@emailid", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniqueCode", UniqueCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtUserName.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailid", txtEmailId.Text.Trim());

            StringBuilder strBody = new StringBuilder();
            //Passing emailid,username and generated unique code via querystring. For testing pass your localhost number and while making online pass your domain name instead of localhost path.
            strBody.Append("<a href=http://localhost:2464/SampleApplication/ResetPassword.aspx?emailId=" + txtEmailId.Text + "&uName=" + txtUserName.Text + "&uCode=" + UniqueCode + ">Click here to change your password</a>");
            // sbody.Append("&uCode=" + uniqueCode + "&uName=" + txtUserName.Text + ">Click here to change your password</a>");

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("sudhakar120693@gmail.com", dr["email"].ToString(), "Reset Your Password", strBody.ToString());
            //pasing the Gmail credentials to send the email

            System.Net.NetworkCredential mailAuthenticaion = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sudhakar120693@gmail.com", "vinothsuresh");

            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient mailclient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
            mailclient.EnableSsl = true;
            mailclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            mailclient.Credentials = mailAuthenticaion;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailclient.Send(mail);
            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            lblStatus.Text = "Reset password link has been sent to your email address";
            txtEmailId.Text = string.Empty;
            txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Please enter valid email address or username";
            txtEmailId.Text = string.Empty;
            txtUserName.Text = string.Empty;
            con.Close();
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Error Occured: " + ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)

Comment: tel me detailly how to send? rajeemcazariazo

Comment: im turned on but it shown a new 16 digit password for app what i do?

Comment: could you disable the two step authentication? and also, please hide your password because it is exposed to the world

Comment: `protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` is Web Forms, not MVC! Please edit your tags.

Comment: sir send some example codings-stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's my bad issue is in my code level.