# Can't send smtp email using C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am trying to send confirm mail using smtp. Here is my code:

```
        var client = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "stmp.gmail.com",
            Port = 465,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password"),
            EnableSsl = true,
        };
        var from = new MailAddress("email@gmail.com", "Confirm mail");
        var to = new MailAddress(message.Destination);

        var mail = new MailMessage(from, to)
        {
            Subject = message.Subject,
            Body = message.Body,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
        };

        client.Send(mail);
```

But I got an error: Failure sending mail. First I got an email from Google said that Google blocked signing in from less secure app and "Google will continue to block sign-in attempts from the app you're using because it has known security problems or is out of date. You can continue to use this app by allowing access to less secure apps, but this may leave your account vulnerable.". After that I have turned on Access for less secure apps but still got the same error.

Anyone have the same problem?

Comment: I have tried using port 587 but still did not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Mail using gmail SMTP from CSharp/.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251189/sending-mail-using-gmail-smtp-from-csharp-net)

Comment: USe 587 and also turn off the security setting of google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)

Comment: @mybirthname I did all but not working

Comment: In your code you have: Host = "stmp.gmail.com"

Pretty sure you transposed some letters in the address. It's likely "smtp.gmail.com"

Comment: Did you use less secure app in Gmail ...if not do it ..