# Does System.Net.Mail currently support SSL

Tags: .net, ssl, system.net.mail

My attempts to send emails using System.Net.Mail work fine, until I switch the port and server accordingly for SSL, and set `SslEnabled` to true; once I do that, the Send times out.

Does SSL work with System.Net.Mail, and if so, what must be done differently other than setting the port and server and the SslEnabled property?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem recently. Turned out that port used for SSL was somehow blocked by a firewall in my company. After talking to IT department, I managed to get it unblocked, and everything started working.

Also, if you happen to use Gmail, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp), there are many suggestions which might help you - you may experience more than one problem at a time.