# sending the email using gmail smtp - unable to connect the remote server

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I tried to send mail using Windows application in C#. I got code as below and tried but it is not working

It  giving following error:

> Unable to connect the remove server

Code:

```
MailAddress sendd = new  MailAddress("xxxxxx@gmail.com","Sethu",Encoding.UTF8);
MailAddress receivee = new MailAddress("xxxxxx@yahoo.com");
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(sendd, receivee);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "yyyyyyy");
mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
client.Send(mail);
```

Anyone help to find out what mistake i did?

Comment: check this NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "yyyyyyy"); email where you have receive email for google or yahoo for allow access for sending email to other

Comment: it seem you have no rights to send mail from this credential

Comment: Add `EnableSsl = true` in your code.

Comment: @NazirUllah how can I find that I dont have rights to send mail?

Comment: @RahulHendawe I already enabled ssl in the code

Comment: yes, Sorry didn't see it. try to change port - Use port 465 instead.

Comment: Have your issue resolve ?

Comment: @RahulHendawe 465 also giving error

Comment: @NazirUllah no not yet.

Comment: first login to the account mail from where you sending the email , check whether you receive any Warning mail or not

Comment: if received then work accordingly then try

Comment: account mail i means this .NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "yyyyyyy");

Comment: Nazir no warning in the mail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115392/discussion-between-sethu-raman-and-nazir-ullah).

Comment: I found message in inner exception "Message=An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.200.109:25"

Answer (score 0):

can you try make your code to something like the following

```
 var smptClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
 {
     Credentials = new NetworkCredential("smit123@gmail.com", "123456789"),
     EnableSsl = true
 };
  smptClient.Send("smit123@gmail.com", "test@gmail.com", "Testing Email", "testing the email");
```

This code is properly tested with my own account on the Network..

Comment: Everything is correct in code. Is there any issue with rights or need to change any smtp settings.

Comment: So may be the issue is in your `NetworkCredentials`, Please check those configuration first, as your code is working perfect

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@gmail.com", "yyyyyyy"),
    EnableSsl = true
};
client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "this is a test email.", "this is my test email body");
```

which is pretty much the same as yours with the difference that it doesn't use MailMessage object. This might not be the problem, but you could give it a try.

I would also check if you have port 587 enable on your server

You should also go through [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp) where you find lots of useful tips

Comment: And if you try to connect to any other SMTP server using this port? It could bey denied on the firewall.

Comment: I found message in inner exception "Message=An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 74.125.200.109:25"

Comment: Is it server or dev machine? are you able to tomporarily disable firewall just to test it's going through?

Comment: It is devlp machine. I tried that too also by disabling firewall and all antivirus