# Send email with gmail smtp vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, gmail

i want to send an email with my gmail account but i have this error and the email doas'nt sent !
http://up.dev-point.com/uploads1/a75d55e308e91.png
My code is :

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click


    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("ihab@gmail.com", "pass")
    Dim mail As New MailMessage("ihab@gmail.com", "ihab@gmail.com", "New", "txt")
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)


End Sub
```

Comment: 1.) Don't include a link to a picture of the error; include the error text *directly in the question itself* 2.) error text in foreign languages are useless to us; translate it into English.

Comment: Don't call anyone bro, ever.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this case, I think you need to make sure SSL is enabled and possibly modify account settings for smtp access.
[Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp/9572958#9572958)

If you need assistance converting the C# code to vb.net let me know