# Sending mail en submit asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to send a mail on form submit but it does'nt work with me

```
            // envoyer mail
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("host");
            //User name and password goes here 


            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress("someone@somewhere.com") };
            mailMessage.To.Add("someone@somewhere.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Hello There";
            mailMessage.Body = "Hello my friend!";

            client.Host = "host";
            client.Port = 25;
            User name and password
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Thank you

Comment: Give some more information. What is happening? Any raised exception? Any error?

Comment: NO errors just form succefully submitted and nothing else

Comment: [Try this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)

Comment: @oumaima: What's the response from the SMTP server?  It's possible that the code is successfully sending an email but the problem is somewhere between the SMTP server and your inbox.

Comment: are you sure you set up 'host' properly? Why don't you use 'localhost' and see if you can receive email locally? PaperCut is good appliation for catching localhost emails

Comment: @jkl with localhost there is A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll

Comment: @oumaima: Well, an exception would explain why the email isn't being sent...

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid thank you.. it works for me now :)