# How to send email to google email?

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp

I have this code to send emails but there is an error .... I searched on google and I saw most of the codes that are used are similar to mine...

```
 MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                    message.From = new MailAddress(test.host.com);
                    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(test@gmail.com));
                    //not the actual email just a dummy value
                    message.Subject = "Sending mail";
                    message.Body = "testing";

                    smtp.Port = 465;
                    smtp.Timeout = 30 * 1000,
                    smtp.Host = "host.com.sg";
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.Send(message);
                    MessageBox.Show("Message has been sent");
```

The new error i received was failure sending mail

Comment: If you have not done so, take a look at this code: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp>

Comment: Make sure your sample account is working..

Comment: You're using the wrong port for starters. Compare your code to a working example in the duplicate.

Comment: I am not using the wrong port because i am not using gmail to send...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to give access to the account to unreliable applications.
Check at: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: tried this method but it still times out...