# SMTP Outlook can't send Emails

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, smtp, office365

i'm stuck in this problem when button click it always says "Failure to send email" I try several host like smtp.office365.com, pod51015.outlook.com and ports like 465, 25 and nothing seems to work

```cs
                string _sender = "myEmail.com";
                string _password = "myPass";

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");

                client.Port = 587;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
                    new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_sender, _password);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Credentials = credentials;

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(_sender, "toEmail.com");
                message.Subject = "mySubject";
                message.Body = "myBody";
                client.Send(message);
```

CTTO of this code which I also found in this forum which seem they worked for them.

Comment: "nothing seems to work" - we need the exception details etc

Comment: take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp

Comment: if I use Gmail SMTP it works just this outlook catching error @Jazb

Comment: if i use Gmail SMTP and Gmail account it works fine while in outlook I get error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email through Gmail SMTP server with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704636/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-server-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Try to change SMTP url to `smtp.office365.com` or `outlook.office365.com` The `smtp-mail.outlook.com` caused me issues (with oAuth).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like mine, except I did force .NET to use TLS 1.2.  TLS 1.1 was deprecated by office365.com in January, and this caused problems with my application.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 SMTP servers no longer allow Basic auth by default - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

Comment: what should be the workaround

Comment: You need to either re-enable Basic auth for your tenant or use OAuth2 for the SMTP connection.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this workaround, it could be helpful.

- Enable Legacy TLS: *Set-TransportConfig -AllowLegacyTLSClients $true​*
- Confirm Legacy TLS is set: *Get-TransportConfig | Format-List AllowLegacyTLSClients*

Change the SMTP endpoint to *smtp-legacy.office365.com*

Comment: How-to use ***AllowLegacyTLSClients***  in NET (C#)  with a SmtpClient class?

Comment: You have to enable the Legacy TLS on your Microsoft Exchange Admin first. Then use _smtp-legacy.office365.com_ as _HOST_